# How do I retain a C++ object in Memory?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, memory-management

What is the object life cycle of a C++ object in an Objective-C class, and how do you keep it in memory?

I tried opaque structure, create instance, but that always leads to null.

Answer (score 6):

You can own a C++ object in your Objective-C class by creating a `new` instance of your C++ class inside of your `init` method, assigning it to an ivar, then in `-dealloc`, call `delete` on the ivar:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
  SomeCPPClass *cpp_object;
}
@end

@implementation SomeClass 

- (id) init {
   self = [super init];
   if(self) {
      cpp_object = new SomeCPPClass();
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
  delete cpp_object;
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: how to asign it to assigning it to an ivar , could you give me more details

Comment: this what I already do , but it not work the function in this class see my pervious question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105177/call-c-class-within-objective-c-one

Answer (score 1):

If your C++ object is going to have the same life-cycle as the Objective-C object which contains it, you can simply place the C++ object (not a pointer to it) in the Objective-C class:

```
@interface MyClass {
    CppObject myObject;
}
@end
```

Comment: Will the constructor be called?

Comment: @WTP: Yes, the constructor will be called. It will behave exactly like you would expect a C++ object to behave.